# Generate XML with Collection of a Collections

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to generate a collection of various collections. All with a common parent and each with a `@XMLRootElement`:

```
@XmlRootElement("as")
public class As extends DTOs {
    @XmlElement("a")
    private Collection collection;
    //
}
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement("bs")
public class Bs extends DTOs {
    @XmlElement("b")
    private Collection collection;
    //
}
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement("b")
public class B extend DTO {
}
```

---

```
public class DTOs extends DTO {
}
```

---

```
public class Element Extend DTO{

    private Collection collection;

    @XmlElementRef
    getCollection() {
        return collection;
    }
}
```

What should be the annonations in `Element` to create:

```
<as>
     <a>
         <name>
     </a>
     <bs>
         <b><foo/></b>
     <bs>
     <cs>
         <c/>
     </cs>
</as>
```

My first attempt was `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` but it thew an exception due to "Illegal annotation". I suppose it was due a collision with the `@XmlElement` in the concrete objects.

When adding `@XmlElementRef` it complains in runtime with a

> unable to marshal type "com.example.Bs" as an element because it is missing an `@XmlRootElement` annotation

I think this might be due to the inheritance.

Comment: I added the 'jaxb' tag and removed the 'sax...' tags as I guess this better fits your requirements, if not please correct the tagging. Did you try to first create an XSD and then generate the corresponding Java classes (this may make your life easier)?

Comment: Why the new question on the same subject? Why not modify your previous question?

Comment: deleted the previous one. I think that this one is clearer

Comment: I think it is more clever to use [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9504954/edit) method.

Comment: And please, simplify it to minimum of classes to highlight the issue, provide 3 things: Source code, Actual XML, Expected XML. This will help helpers, and won't make haters hate.

Comment: @UdoFholl - I know you don't habitually delete questions then re-ask, but my advice would be to edit the original instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a common root you can use @XmlElementRef:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Without a common root you can use @XmlAnyElement(lax=true):

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Answer (score 0):

you should define the schema and use this schema to generate JAXB classes. With those classes you can do transformation to and from XML.

Comment: I would like to achieve it with annotations only. No schema but thanks for your answer